# ActiveRecord query changing when a dot/period is in condition value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

*See the updates at the bottom. I've narrowed this down significantly.*

I've also created a barebones app demonstrating this bug: https://github.com/coreyward/bug-demo

And I've also created a bug ticket in the official tracker: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/6611-activerecord-query-changing-when-a-dotperiod-is-in-condition-value

If someone can either tell me how to monkey-patch this or explain where this is happening in Rails I'd be very grateful.

---

I'm getting some bizarre/unexpected behavior. That'd lead me to believe either there is a bug (confirmation that this is a bug would be a perfect answer), or I am missing something that is right under my nose (or that I don't understand).

#### The Code

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :portfolio
  default_scope order(:ordinal)
end

class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :galleries
end

# later, in a controller action
scope = Portfolio.includes(:galleries) # eager load galleries
if some_condition
  @portfolio = scope.find_by_domain('domain.com')
else
  @portfolio = scope.find_by_vanity_url('vanity_url')
end
```

- I have `Portfolios` which can have multiple `Galleries` each.
- The `galleries` have `ordinal`, `vanity_url`, and `domain` attributes.
- The `gallery` `ordinals` are set as integers from zero on up. I've confirmed that this works as expected by checking `Gallery.where(:portfolio_id => 1).map &:ordinal`, which returns `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` as expected.
- Both `vanity_url` and `domain` are `t.string, :null => false` columns with unique indexes.

#### The Problem

If `some_condition` is true and `find_by_domain` is run, the galleries returned do not respect the default scope. If `find_by_vanity_url` is run, the galleries are ordered according to the default scope. I looked at the queries being generated, and they are *very* different.

#### The Queries

```
# find_by_domain SQL: (edited out additional selected columns for brevity)

Portfolio Load (2.5ms)  SELECT DISTINCT `portfolios`.id FROM `portfolios` LEFT OUTER JOIN `galleries` ON `galleries`.`portfolio_id` = `portfolios`.`id` WHERE `portfolios`.`domain` = 'lvh.me' LIMIT 1
Portfolio Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `portfolios`.`id` AS t0_r0, `portfolios`.`vanity_url` AS t0_r2, `portfolios`.`domain` AS t0_r11, `galleries`.`id` AS t1_r0, `galleries`.`portfolio_id` AS t1_r1, `galleries`.`ordinal` AS t1_r6 FROM `portfolios` LEFT OUTER JOIN `galleries` ON `galleries`.`portfolio_id` = `portfolios`.`id` WHERE `portfolios`.`domain` = 'lvh.me' AND `portfolios`.`id` IN (1)

# find_by_vanity_url SQL:

Portfolio Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `portfolios`.* FROM `portfolios` WHERE `portfolios`.`vanity_url` = 'cw' LIMIT 1
Gallery Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `galleries`.* FROM `galleries` WHERE (`galleries`.portfolio_id = 1) ORDER BY ordinal
```

So the query generated by `find_by_domain` doesn't have an `ORDER` statement, hence things aren't being ordered as desired. My question is...

**Why is this happening? What is prompting Rails 3 to generate different queries to these two columns?**

---

#### Update

This is really strange. I've considered and ruled out all of the following:

- Indexes on the columns
- Reserved/special words in Rails
- A column name collision between the tables (ie. domain being on both tables)
- The field type, both in the DB and Schema
- The "allow null" setting
- The separate scope

I get the same behavior as `find_by_vanity_url` with location, phone, and title; I get the same behavior as `find_by_domain` with email.

---

#### Another Update

I've narrowed it down to *when the parameter has a period (.) in the name*:

```
find_by_something('localhost') # works fine
find_by_something('name_routed_to_127_0_0_1') # works fine
find_by_something('my_computer.local') # fails
find_by_something('lvh.me') #fails
```

I'm not familiar enough with the internals to say where the query formed might change based on the value of a `WHERE` condition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference between the two strategies for eager loading are discussed in the comments here

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/association_preload.rb

From the documentation:

```
# The second strategy is to use multiple database queries, one for each
# level of association. Since Rails 2.1, this is the default strategy. In
# situations where a table join is necessary (e.g. when the +:conditions+
# option references an association's column), it will fallback to the table
# join strategy.
```

I believe that the dot in "foo.bar" is causing active record to think that you are putting a condition on a table that is outside of the originating model which prompts the second strategy discussed in the documentation.

The two separate queries runs one with the Person model and the second with the Item model.

```
 Person.includes(:items).where(:name => 'fubar')

Person Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."name" = 'fubar'
Item Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE ("items".person_id = 1) ORDER BY items.ordinal
```

Because you run the second query against the Item model, it inherits the default scope where you specified `order(:ordinal)`.

The second query, which it attempts eager loading with the full runs off the person model and will not use the default scope of the association.

```
 Person.includes(:items).where(:name => 'foo.bar')

Person Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "people"."id" AS t0_r0, "people"."name" AS t0_r1, 
"people"."created_at" AS t0_r2, "people"."updated_at" AS t0_r3, "items"."id" AS t1_r0, 
"items"."person_id" AS t1_r1, "items"."name" AS t1_r2, "items"."ordinal" AS t1_r3, 
"items"."created_at" AS t1_r4, "items"."updated_at" AS t1_r5 FROM "people" LEFT OUTER JOIN 
"items" ON "items"."person_id" = "people"."id" WHERE "people"."name" = 'foo.bar'
```

It is a little buggy to think that, but I can see how it would be with the several different ways you can present a list of options, the way to be sure that you catch all of them would be to scan the completed "WHERE" conditions for a dot and use the second strategy, and they leave it that way because both strategies are functional. I would actually go as far as saying that the aberrant behavior is in the first query, not the second. If you would like the ordering to persist for this query, I recommend one of the following:

1)  If you want the association to have an order by when it is called, then you can specify that with the association. Oddly enough, this is in the documentation, but I could not get it to work.

Source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, :order => 'items.ordinal'
end
```

2) Another method would be to just add the order statement to the query in question.

```
Person.includes(:items).where(:name => 'foo.bar').order('items.ordinal')
```

3) Along the same lines would be setting up a named scope

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  named_scope :with_items, includes(:items).order('items.ordinal')
end
```

And to call that:

```
Person.with_items.where(:name => 'foo.bar')
```

Comment: I still haven't fully digested this, but thanks for the detailed information. Another issue with the '.' condition is that attributes aren't loaded immediately so things like `after initialize { self.name ||= 'default' }` fail with a missing attribute error. This doesn't seem like the expected behavior, but maybe I'm missing something still.

Comment: Well, that is very interesting. I think you found a bug. I confess, I do not use after initialize that much, because of the overhead when searches are used. It appears to instantiate several empty "Person" methods as part of the eager loading. To work around it, I did this: `after initialize { self.name ||= 'default' if defined?(self.name) }`

Comment: These workarounds won't work in all scenarios such as when joining to one child table for the find operation and then again to that same child table for the include. Such as: find all posts with comments in the last month and then include all comments from the last year. Left outer joins won't work here without better aliasing (which is also broken). Also, the child's child table was dropped for some reason.

Comment: My current dirty workaround is to encode/decode the dots like this: `.where("people.name = REPLACE(?, '&dot;', '.')", somename.gsub!(".", "&dot;"))`

Answer (score 5):

This is [issue #950 on the Rails GitHub project](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/950). It looks like implicit eager loading (which is what causes this bug) has been deprecated in Rails 3.2 and removed in Rails 4.0. Instead, you'll explicitly tell Rails that you need a JOIN for the WHERE clause — e.g.:

```
Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.title = 'lol'").references(:comments)
```

If you desperately need this bug fixed in Rails 3.1.*, you can hack `ActiveRecord::Relation#tables_in_string` to be less aggressive in matching table names. I created [a Gist of my (inelegant and slow) solution](https://gist.github.com/1684228). This is the diff:

```
diff --git a/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb b/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb
index 30f1824..d7335f3 100644
--- a/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb
+++ b/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb
@@ -528,7 +528,13 @@ module ActiveRecord
       return [] if string.blank?
       # always convert table names to downcase as in Oracle quoted table names are in uppercase
       # ignore raw_sql_ that is used by Oracle adapter as alias for limit/offset subqueries
-      string.scan(/([a-zA-Z_][.\w]+).?\./).flatten.map{ |s| s.downcase }.uniq - ['raw_sql_']
+      candidates = string.scan(/([a-zA-Z_][.\w]+).?\./).flatten.map{ |s| s.downcase }.uniq - ['raw_sql_']
+      candidates.reject do |t|
+        s = string.partition(t).first
+        s.chop! if s.last =~ /['"]/
+        s.reverse!
+        s =~ /^\s*=/
+      end
     end
   end
 end
```

It only works for my very specific case (Postgres and an equality condition), but maybe you can alter it to work for you.

Comment: Still a bug in Rails 3.2.13, moving on to Rails 4 for a solution.

Comment: On 4.0.11 and just started getting this