# Rails Active Record Query Generation -- Strange behavior when using includes and dot('.')

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a business model and an address model like this

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, as: :addressable
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Now the strange part. If I run the following

```
Business.includes(:address).where(['email like ?', '%whatever%'])
```

Two Queries are generated

```
SELECT `businesses`.* FROM `businesses` WHERE (email like '%whatever%')
SELECT `addresses`.* FROM `addresses` WHERE `addresses`.`addressable_type` = 'Business' AND `addresses`.`addressable_id` IN (26)
```

But If The text that will appear inside the like clause has a dot('.') like the below

```
Business.includes(:address).where(['email like ?', '%what.ever%'])
```

This time a single query is generated using the JOIN

```
SELECT `businesses`.`id` AS t0_r0, `businesses`.`name` AS t0_r1, `businesses`.`primary_category_id` AS t0_r2, `businesses`.`secondary_category_id` AS t0_r3, `businesses`.`sub_primary_category_id` AS t0_r4, `businesses`.`sub_secondary_category_id` AS t0_r5, `businesses`.`website` AS t0_r6, `businesses`.`phone` AS t0_r7, `businesses`.`manager_name` AS t0_r8, `businesses`.`manager_phone` AS t0_r9, `businesses`.`email` AS t0_r10, `businesses`.`created_at` AS t0_r11, `businesses`.`updated_at` AS t0_r12, `businesses`.`encrypted_password` AS t0_r13, `businesses`.`reset_password_token` AS t0_r14, `businesses`.`reset_password_sent_at` AS t0_r15, `businesses`.`remember_created_at` AS t0_r16, `businesses`.`sign_in_count` AS t0_r17, `businesses`.`current_sign_in_at` AS t0_r18, `businesses`.`last_sign_in_at` AS t0_r19, `businesses`.`current_sign_in_ip` AS t0_r20, `businesses`.`last_sign_in_ip` AS t0_r21, `businesses`.`confirmation_token` AS t0_r22, `businesses`.`confirmed_at` AS t0_r23, `businesses`.`confirmation_sent_at` AS t0_r24, `businesses`.`failed_attempts` AS t0_r25, `businesses`.`unlock_token` AS t0_r26, `businesses`.`locked_at` AS t0_r27, `addresses`.`id` AS t1_r0, `addresses`.`line1` AS t1_r1, `addresses`.`line2` AS t1_r2, `addresses`.`city` AS t1_r3, `addresses`.`country` AS t1_r4, `addresses`.`zip` AS t1_r5, `addresses`.`neighbourhood` AS t1_r6, `addresses`.`addressable_id` AS t1_r7, `addresses`.`addressable_type` AS t1_r8, `addresses`.`created_at` AS t1_r9, `addresses`.`updated_at` AS t1_r10, `addresses`.`latitude` AS t1_r11, `addresses`.`longitude` AS t1_r12, `addresses`.`gmaps` AS t1_r13 FROM `businesses` LEFT OUTER JOIN `addresses` ON `addresses`.`addressable_id` = `businesses`.`id` AND `addresses`.`addressable_type` = 'Business' WHERE (email like '%what.ever%')
```

I have tried with different values for the like clause, and noticed that the JOIN query is only generated when the input has a dot('.') and there are atleast 2 chars before the dot('.').

Few examples

- 'whatever' results in 2 Queries without JOIN
- 'w.hatever' results in 2 Queries without JOIN
- 'w.h' results in 2 Queries without JOIN
- 'w.ha' results in 2 Queries without JOIN
- 'w.' results in 2 Queries without JOIN
- 'xxxxxxxxw.hatever' results in 1 Query with JOIN
- 'what.ever' results in 1 Query with JOIN
- 'wh.' results in 1 Query with Join

My Guess is this has got something to do with Rails thinking that if there is a dot in the where clause It may refer to another table so a join should be applied and if there isn't a dot or if there is only one char before the dot ( may be table names can't of a single char that's y.. A guess!!) than it generates 2 queries.

Anyone has seen this kind of issue? I am using Rails 3.2

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199235/activerecord-query-changing-when-a-dot-period-is-in-condition-value

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I will accept if you move it to answer